# Can't compile LINQ extension methods on classes that derive from a class implementing IEnumerable<out T>

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have a situation where I've got non-generic and generic implementations of some sort of `Item` and `Collection` classes, where the collection must contain Items and the generic collection must contain generic items of a specific type.

```
public class Item { }

public class Item<T>: Item  {  }

public class MyList : IEnumerable<Item>  {  
    public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator() { }
}

public class MyList<T> : MyList, IEnumerable<Item<T>>  { 
    public new IEnumerator<Item<T>> GetEnumerator() { }
}
```

The problem is that Linq extension methods don't work on the generic version of the list:

```
// works
var test1 = new MyList().Any();

// intellisense understands this, but it won't compile
var test2 = new MyList<int>().Any();
```

This is using .NET 4.5.  I assume this has something to do with the presence of two conflicting interfaces, `IEnumerable<Item>` and `IEnumerable<Item<T>>`. What I would expect is for the derived one to take precedence.

Why won't this compile, and what's the right way to implement something like this so I can expose the `IEnumerable<T>` interface in both the non-generic and generic versions of the collection class? Everything works fine if I just remove the `IEnumerable<Item>` interface from the nongeneric version, but then of course I can't enumerate over it without exposing it via some other non-standard method.

`Error: MyList<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'Item<T>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: What do you mean it "won't compile"?  Did the compiler provide an error message?

Comment: You shouldn't name a class `List<T>`, as it's a well known built-in CLR type.

Comment: This isn't really the name of the class. I changed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Kirk yes, "does not contain a definition for `...` and no extension method `...` accepting a first argument of type ... could be found. Updated the q.

Comment: Why would you expect the *more derived* one to take precedence? The more derived one is more specific; the less derived one is more general. Why is "more specific" obviously better than "more general"? Both specificity and generality have their benefits; the C# compiler does not try to read your mind and decide for you whether you prefer specificity or generality. Rather, it makes you state which you prefer rather than guessing for you and possibly getting it wrong.

Comment: Think about it this way. You've got a class that can be treated as both a sequence of animals -- which might contain giraffes or tigers -- and as a sequence of tigers. Now you use that class in a context where it is being used as a sequence of *something*. Why should the compiler logically deduce that "something" is meant to be tigers, excluding the giraffes?

Comment: Well, the source of my confusion is primarily because Intellisense only presents you with the more-derived version.

Comment: ... also what I don't say in this simplified example is that the non-generic collection class is abstract, you would never have a collection containing something other than the specific type. I don't expect the compiler to know this though, in the context of this discussion, I'm really just trying to figure out the best way to implement something I understand conceptually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `MyList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` twice, so the compiler can't infer the type of the generic argument of `Enumerable.Any<TSource>`.

You have to explicitly specify which `T` you want to use:

```
var test2 = new MyList<int>().Any<Item>();
// or
var test2 = new MyList<int>().Any<Item<int>>();
```

Unfortunately, the error message is not really good at transporting this information. If you call the extension method with the normal syntax, the message is very clear.

Call:

```
var test2 = Enumerable.Any(new MyList<int>());
```

Results in:

> The type arguments for method '`System.Linq.Enumerable.Any<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)`' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Why wouldn't the derived implementation take precedence as the "new" method when operating against a concrete instance? That is, the `GetEnumerator<Item>` method is not available on a concrete instance of `MyList<T>`

Comment: @JamieTreworgy: The method `IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator` certainly is available.

Comment: `IEnumerator<Item<T>> GetEnumerator()` clearly hides `IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()` in the derived class. It's only available if I cast to the base class interface explicitly.

Comment: @JamieTreworgy: That doesn't make it go away. `Enumerable.Any<TSource>` doesn't take a `MyList<T>`. It takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter. And that is the important point: If you cast `MyList<T>` to `IEnumerable<Item>`, enumerating it will use `IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator`!

Comment: Oh I get it. Because the extension method operates against the interface, it has no knowledge of the concrete class heirarchy. It's interesting that intellisense does seem to operate only against the concrete class, though, since it shows only the derived version, fooling you into thinking it's going to work..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the type implements `IEnumerable<T>` more than once, for different values of `T`.  A simpler reproduction would be this:

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<string>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now the code `new Foo().Any();` doesn't know whether it's calling `Any` on an `IEnumerable<int>` or an `IEnumerable<string>`.

In your case `MyList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<Item>` and `IEnumerable<Item<T>>`.  It doesn't know which one to use.

By not relying on generic argument inference and specifying the type explicitly you can solve that problem.  `new MyList<int>().Any<Item<int>>();` compiles just fine.  `new MyList<int>().Any<Item>();` would also work.

Comment: Upvoted for great example, giving it to the other guy who beat you by 2 minutes.